# How do you get two divs have the same borderRadius?

Tags: javascript, html, border

Is this the right way to match two divs?

```
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("div2");
div2.style.borderRadius = "100px"

document.getElementById("div1").style.borderRadius = div2.style.borderRadius;
```

Just a newbie at javascript.

Comment: you missed a semicolon `div2.style.borderRadius = "100px";`

Comment: Show HTML please. If you select by class then you get an array back. It seems you are confusing getting elements by Id and/or by Classname

Comment: What do you mean by match? Are you trying to make them match, or check if they match?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that,`document.getElementsByClassName("div2");` returns an ARRAY-like object of all elements which have all of the given class names,not a direct reference.

Use it this way,

```
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("d2");
div2[0].style.borderRadius = "100px";

document.getElementById("d1").style.borderRadius = div2[0].style.borderRadius;
```

CHECK this Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ft1Ljggn/8/

Answer (score 0):

Just to comment on your code, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection, not a single DOM element. You should use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` if you're trying to just get one element.

And you normally don't want to use JS to add styling, unless the styling you want to use is dynamic. For this case, you should use a CSS file and add a class:

```
.round-border {
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

If you still want to use JS to add the class instead of putting it in the HTML, you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById("div1").classList.add('round-border');
document.getElementById("div2").classList.add('round-border');
```

This is assuming you gave your HTML elements the correct ID names.

But like I said, because you are using a static value of `100px`, it would make more sense to add this class to your elements in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Get ID and below this code..

var target = document.getElementById("div1");
    target.style.borderRadius = "100px";

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single line code, hope it helps:

```
div1.style.borderRadius = window.getComputedStyle(div2).getPropertyValue('border-radius');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6rnb8owe/1/)**

You can possibly play with `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` to achieve comparison of two properties as well. You need not put some extra efforts to get the arrays logic into it.

Answer (score 0):

Varun's answer is good; Another way, especially if you want to have more similarly styled DIVs, or have more common attributes such as colour/border etc, is to define a CSS class, and apply that class to the DIVs, e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .roundedcorners{
    border-radius:100px;
    border: 2px solid #8AC007; 
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1" class="roundedcorners">Content 1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="roundedcorners">Content 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can still set position, size etc. on the individual DIVs (even have them overlap if you like).